# Change stylesheet on form selection onChange="change()"

Tags: php, jquery, css, forms

So I am trying to make my stylesheets change when a user selects a dropdown box in a form to a different one.

My code is as follows.

```
$styles = array(
    "style",
    "dark"
);

$style = $_POST["style"];

if (!in_array($style, $styles))
{
     //we default back to the first in the array, this prevents accidental hardcoding;
     $style = $styles[0]; 
}

$css = "/templates/streamer/css/$style.css";

if (!file_exists($css)){
    //something terrible happend;
    #echo "missing style $css";
}

function showOptions() {
    echo '<form id="selectStyle" action="#" method="post">';
    echo '<select id="style" onChange="change()">';

    global $styles;

    foreach ($styles as &$value){
        echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select></form>';
}
```

then my link rel is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $css; ?>"/>
```

Then I call the jquery script:

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById("selectStyle").submit();
}
```

Then I call the function to display the form:

```
<?php showOptions(); echo $css; ?>
```

So my problem is, that once I select the "dark" css file, the page kinda refreshes and doesn't change the stylesheet.

I have also tried many other alternative methods and they dont work either. But this method I wrote seems to be the better option that suits my needs.

Thanks

Comment: I need to change stylesheet, the option and method you said is not what i need. Thanks though

Comment: the page refresh after form submission ? or after the event `onChange` ?

Comment: Split your HTML from your PHP, there is no need to have to `echo` it out when you can just close the PHP tags. That way it is easier to read and understand.

Comment: Can you show that the `change()` function is doing? Perhaps the problem is there. Since you don't have a submit button, that's my guess.

Comment: @hassan - it refresh when i select dark in the dropdown box. the form doesnt have a submit button.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel my bad i forgot to add the jquey to the question, let me edit it lol

Comment: so, show your change function

Comment: @hassan I have now sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are mixing between PHP and Javascript

here :

```
echo '<select id="style" onChange="change()">';
```

you need to specify a `name` attribute to *contact* with PHP -so to speak-

so this needs to be changed to:

```
echo '<select name="style" onChange="change()">';
```

Comment: wow lol, annoyed with myself that it was just that 'name' that caused the issue. Thanks soo much for your help :) Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having a similar issue, and thanks again to @hassan for helping me.

I have now just edited the form and added a echo for the function:

```
function showOptions() {
    echo '<form id="selectStyle" action="#" method="post">';
    echo '<select name="style" onChange="change()">';
    echo '<option disabled selected value> -- select a style -- </option>';
    global $styles;

foreach ($styles as &$value){
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select></form>';
}
```

So the line I added was the extra option for select a style:

```
echo '<option disabled selected value> -- select a style -- </option>';
```

So now this allows me to switch between my 2 styles. I will be adding a lot more styles ro choose from. but needed to get this to work first before i could make my other style files.

Thanks again for the help everyone and hassan for the Answer :)